# Send a Facebook Message with XMPP using Access Tokens in Python

Tags: python, facebook, xmpp, xmpppy

This is a very specific question, but I cannot find any documentation on how I can do it. The Facebook Documentation is [pretty vague](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/#platauth) with some *horrible* and useless PHP examples (really, it's code like the Facebook PHP Sample Code that make people think PHP sucks)  but I cannot find anything around for Python.

I can't even work out how to apply the same principles from the PHP sample code into a Python world. The xmpppy and SleekXMPP docs are a bit bare (or [broken](http://sleekxmpp.com/sasl.html)) and Google only shows examples of people using passwords.

I have the access tokens coming from the database, I have no interest in spawning a browser to find stuff, or doing anything else to find a token. I have them, consider it a hardcoded string. I want to pass that string to XMPP and send a message, that is the whole scope of things.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered this with a link to a blog I wrote because it described the solution perfectly, but apparently that annoyed some moderators.

While that's clearly ridiculous, here is the answer reposted.

```
import sleekxmpp
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class SendMsgBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):
    def init(self, jid, recipient, message):
        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, 'ignore')
        # The message we wish to send, and the JID that
        # will receive it.
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.msg = message
        # The session_start event will be triggered when
        # the bot establishes its connection with the server
        # and the XML streams are ready for use. We want to
        # listen for this event so that we we can initialize
        # our roster.
        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start, threaded=True)
    def start(self, event):
        self.send_presence()
        self.get_roster()
        self.send_message(mto=self.recipient, mbody=self.msg, mtype='chat')
        # Using wait=True ensures that the send queue will be
        #emptied before ending the session.
        self.disconnect(wait=True)
```

I shoved that in a file called fbxmpp.py, then in another file (your worker, your command line app, your Flask controller, whatever) you'll need something like the following:

```
from fbxmpp import SendMsgBot

# The "From" Facebook ID
jid = '511501255@chat.facebook.com'

# The "Recipient" Facebook ID, with a hyphen for some reason
to = '-1000023894758@chat.facebook.com'

# Whatever you're sending
msg = 'Hey Other Phil, how is it going?'

xmpp = SendMsgBot(jid, to, unicode(msg))

xmpp.credentials['api_key'] = '123456'
xmpp.credentials['access_token'] = 'your-access-token'

if xmpp.connect(('chat.facebook.com', 5222)):
    xmpp.process(block=True)
    print("Done")
else:
    print("Unable to connect.")
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code worked, **but only after some modifications** mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21452035/977116)