# Send facebook messages via SleekXMPP

Tags: python, xmpp, facebook-chat

I am trying to send a message on facebook chat with sleekXMPP, using the answer from here as a boilerplate: [Send a Facebook Message with XMPP using Access Tokens in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902171/send-a-facebook-message-with-xmpp-using-access-tokens-in-python)

My code is

```
import sleekxmpp

class SendMsgBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):
    def init(self, jid, recipient, message):

        print "..."

        sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, 'ignore')
        self.recipient = recipient
        self.msg = message
        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.start, threaded=True)

    def start(self, event):
        self.send_presence()
        self.get_roster()
        self.send_message(mto=self.recipient, mbody=self.msg, mtype='chat')

        self.disconnect(wait=True)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    xmpp = SendMsgBot(from_id, to_id, unicode(message))

    xmpp.credentials['apikey'] = api_key
    xmpp.credentials['accesstoken'] = o_auth_token

    if xmpp.connect(('chat.facebook.com', 5222)):
        xmpp.process(block=True)
        print("Done")
    else:
        print("Unable to connect")
```

However, when I run the script I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sendMessagesScript.py", line 33, in <module>
    xmpp = SendMsgBot(from_id, to_id, unicode(message))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/clientxmpp.py", line 112, in __init__
    self.register_plugin('feature_starttls')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sleekxmpp/basexmpp.py", line 264, in register_plugin
    pconfig = self.plugin_config.get(plugin, {})
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

In the class SendMsgBot(sleekxmpp.ClientXMPP):, you need to change

**def init(self, jid, recipient, message)** to **def __*init*__(self, jid, recipient, message)**

I hope it will work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. -- A bit of an explanation or a reference would have been nice. Most people are more interested in actually understanding what they're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Additionally, it seems that some important dashes have been ommitted from the original code.

I also had to change

```
xmpp.credentials['apikey'] = api_key
xmpp.credentials['accesstoken'] = o_auth_token
```

to

```
xmpp.credentials['api_key'] = api_key
xmpp.credentials['access_token'] = o_auth_token
```

These are apparently the parameter names that Facebook expects, as you can see in Facebook's PHP [example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/)